# PHP cannot write to file

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using `file_get_contents` to write to a file, as follows:

```
<?php
    file_put_contents('address', $users);
?>
```

Where `'address'` is actually the address I'm using (a url), which works because I'm reading from this file correctly. I'm calling this php file, `updateusers.php`, from a `jquery` function:

```
$.get("address", {users: registeredusers});
```

Where `registeredusers` is defined as follows:

```
registeredusers += "\n" + document.getElementById("newusername").value + "," + document.getElementById("newpassword").value + "," + document.getElementById("newemail").value;
```

Basically I'm trying to get the values of text fields, separate them by commas, then append these to the variable `registeredusers` and write that to a txt file I have. But then I download that file and see nothing has been written. Why is this happening? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing not sufficient file system access.

Comment: I changed the file permissions to 606 (public permissions Read and Write), but no writing takes place yet

Comment: file_gets_contents and file_put_contents is separate things.  " if the fopen wrappers have been enabled"  http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php, you may be able to read a file but not write to them for several reasons.  Is the file on your server, do you have the url file wrappers enabled, does the php user have enough permission to write to the file etc..  I would say if its on the same machine, use the path.  Most likely when accessing the page from the url wrapper you may be treated by the filesystem as public.  I am not sure as I always use a filesystem path and not a url

Comment: I changed the url to using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and I also had to check if `users` was set, with `if (isset($_GET['users']))`, but it's working now. If it weren't for your idea of permission I might have not remembered to use the root to store. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've been told, using a URL to write requires more permission. So since I'm calling this file from my own hosting space, I changed the line

```
file_put_contents('address', $users);
```

To this:

```
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'address within hosting space', $users);
```

But this by itself wouldn't work, I had to actually declare that a variable, in this case under the name of `users` would be set. Then if so, assign that value to an actual declaration of `$users` then write it:

```
if (isset($_GET['users'])) {
    $users = $_GET['users'];
    file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'address within hosting space', $users);      
}
```

This last block is the code that worked to write to a file (not appending though)